# Spark Shell Yarn Client Mode - Akka AssociationError

Tags: apache-spark, akka

When I launch Spark Shell using:
spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client

I'm getting the following error:

```
16/03/21 20:52:29 ERROR ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ipaddress10:47915] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@hostname02:48703]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tc
p://sparkExecutor@hostname02:48703]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@hostname02:48703]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: No route to host
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/03/21 20:52:29 ERROR ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ipaddress10:47915] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@hostname02:48703]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tc
p://sparkExecutor@hostname02:48703]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@hostname02:48703]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: No route to host
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/03/21 20:52:32 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 3 on hostname01: remote Rpc client disassociated
16/03/21 20:52:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 3 (epoch 0)
16/03/21 20:52:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
16/03/21 20:52:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(3, hostname01, 37497)
16/03/21 20:52:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 3 successfully in removeExecutor
16/03/21 20:52:32 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 3 has been removed (new total is 0)
```

Firewall & Iptables are turned off. Machines in the cluster are mutually ping-able on all the ports.
But i'm puzzled why I'm still getting "akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: No route to host"

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a name resolution issue. You should try using IP addresses in your settings (for instance in `slaves` file) rather than names to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: I think the question is about spark on Yarn, so the `slaves` file has no impact

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem before. I found that I have mistyped some environement variables regarding SPARK_LOCAL_IP and SPARK_LOCAL_DNS

To resolve your problem, you have to:

- In all your nodemanager nodes, check the .bashrc and .bash_profile files that you have set the env variables to right values : `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` and `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS`, then restart your nodemanger(s)
- In your client machine (where you issue the command `spark-shell`) set the values of the previous env variables to your client machine IP and hostname